# Question could be answered well on Stack Overflow but gets closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I am not surprised this question got closed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126943/scientific-computing-in-python-fortran-vs-c

However, I feel like Stack Overflow could have provided some very useful answers that would have benefited people. Some of the best questions on here I'm amazed weren't immediately closed because they seem broad or opinion based but they end up getting some fantastic answers.

If Stack Overflow isn't the place for asking a question like that, where is?

Comment: This is not a great place to ask what might be on topic on other web sites.  You asked yet another off topic question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think it will be cool to have a forum for more opinion based question/answers.

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Comment: [Why are the best questions the ones which have been closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200122); [Why are useful questions on Stack Overflow being closed as non-constructive?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110350)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question has now been, quite rightly, deleted. It was this:

> What are the pros and cons of Fortran vs C, for optimising time critical functions that you then intend to call from Python, when performing scientific computing.
>
> Please just give the important facts.

There are several things wrong with this:

1. It's too broad. You are asking people to write the equivalent of an essay or short book, not a few paragraphs.
2. It's opinion based. What one person thinks is a pro for FORTRAN others will consider a con.
3. It sounds like it could be an essay question from a university course.

These type of questions, while they might be useful, don't work on Stack Exchange so we tend to close them down quite quickly.

Comment: Ok, points taken. Just as an example however, this was a very good question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146159/is-fortran-faster-than-c. Is the main difference just that 'interfacing for scientific computing in Python' is not as specific as 'which is faster'?

Comment: @rwolst That question was asked back in 2008. Were it to be asked today it would probably be closed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. From the number of upvotes/answers/favourites it seems like there should be a place for these questions somewhere (although as I am now aware, not Stack Overflow).

Comment: @rwolst Nowhere at Stack Exchange I'm afraid.
["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @gnat Why didn't it work out? Perhaps it just wasn't implemented properly or not given enough attention.

Comment: @Jase see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6759/31260) for a more elaborate explanation

Comment: @gnat Thanks for getting back; I didn't think it would be relevant but I ended up reading that page and found the answer right after I oringinally messaged you. But thanks :)